# Openspan 5.2 visual studio 2010 plugin issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I had recently upgrade openspan 5.1 to 5.2 which is compatible to framework 4.0 and visual studio 2010 SP1. now this gives error like

### Remotesoft Protector Runtime Error – yet to handle multiple .NET framework runtime

which seems to be thord party plugin error.
After check in "clrver" it shows

OpenSpan.Runtime.exe v2.0.50727

i cant find any Option to change this to version v4.0
on some search i just got a link

> http://www.geospecialling.com/index.php/2011/11/remotesoft-protector-runtime-error-yet-to-handle-multiple-net-framework-runtime/

it shows there is only way to change this is "protector.exe" command!
as it is embedded to openspan plug in i can find only some dlls there. please help me on this. thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the .NET 3.5 runtime not 4.0 and this error will go away